# How to encode array in php, save it an a cookie, edit it in js and save it again?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, cookies

the title pretty much states what I want to do. I have a php array which I need to encode and save in a cookie, then I want to read and edit it using js and save it back.

Here is what I've tried so far but to no result

file.php

```
    $arrayToEncode = array("test" => true, "test2" => false);
    setcookie("cookiename", json_encode($arrayToEncode), time() + 365 * 24 * 60 * 60, '/');
```

jsfile.js

```
    // readCookie is a function that given the key of the cookie it returns the value of it        
    var cookieArray = JSON.parse(readCookie("announcements")); 
    cookieArray["test"] = false;
    console.log(cookieArray);
```

What I get is an error for the first line in the jsfile

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token %

Thanks a lot for any help :)

Edit: The cookie value that gets added from php is

> %7B%22test%22%3Atrue%2C%22test2%22%3Afalse%7D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to decode the string you get from cookie

```
console.log(jQuery.parseJSON(decodeURIComponent(cookie)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems correct - except from a simple syntax error:

```
$arrayToEncode = array("test" => true, "test2 => false);
```

You forgot to close the quotes

```
"test2" => false
```

Comment: Oops this was a typo on my example code, I don't have this error on the actual code.

Answer (score 0):

I assume the problem is in the `readCookie()`.

Use this plugin instead:

https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie

JS Using the above plugin

```
    var cookieValue = JSON.parse($.cookie("cookiename"));
    $.removeCookie("cookiename");
    cookieValue['test'] = false;
    $.cookie.json = true;
    $.cookie("cookiename", cookieValue, { expires : 10 });
```

This works fine.

Initial value: `%7B%22test%22%3Afalse%2C%22test2%22%3Afalse%7D`

Updated value : `%7B%22test%22%3Atrue%2C%22test2%22%3Afalse%7D`

Comment: Thanks a lot for the plugin, however I used the answer from Jitendra since I want to keep my readCookie function.